# Finite fundamental group and covering spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Show that if a path-connected, locally path-connected space X has a finite 
 fundamental group , then every map $X$ to $S^1 \times S^1$ is nullhomotopic (i.e. homotopic to a constant map) .

Is the same true if we replace the torus with the wedge sum of two circles?

I was able to solve the first part using that the fundamental group of the covering space: $R \times R$ is trivial, but regarding the second part, about the wedge sum of two circles, I think the issue is that the fundamental group of the covering space of the wedge sum is not trivial,is my intuition true? or I am missing something?

Comment: 5 months being a member and  and 16 questions asked? About time to learn the easy rules to properly write mathematics in this site: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-qu%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bick-reference

Comment: @Timbuc thank you ,, I was planing to learn Latex  in  summer  ,but this will help for now , i appreciate it .

Comment: I think he also means that you could use some spacing, that makes it more easy to read. Just add a few new lines, that makes it often more smooth to read. :)

Comment: also thank you :) I will next time @Pedro

Comment: Ok let me explain what I have done and why. I first placed the question you found somewhere in a book or course in one block. After that, I made a new block with your personal question regarding to the problem. Then I made a last block with all the attempts you made. Then it is immediatly clear for everyone: (a) what the original question was you needed to solve, (b) what your personal question is, and (c) what you tried to solve that personal question. :)

Comment: i just did .thanks

Comment: When you say "*... the fundamental group of the covering space of the wedge sum is not trivial, ...*", which covering are you refering to?

Comment: I Have found some covering spaces in hatcher page 58 that are not trivial, but my problem is that this is not really a contradiction since i didn't prove that there is no non- trivial covering space @StefanHamcke

Comment: @Pedro thank you   I  really appreciate your help

Comment: Did you really intend to put three *no*'s into the last sentence of your comment :-) Don't you rather mean that you didn't prove that there is no trivial covering space?

Comment: yes sry i meant there's no trivial covering space. @StefanHamcke

Comment: If by trivial you mean simply-connected, then note that there always exists a trivial covering space of $X$ when $X$ is path-connected, locally path-connected and semi-locally simply-connected. In particular, $S^1\vee S^1$ has a simply-connected covering space, which is presented at page 59 of Hatcher's book.

Answer (score 1):

Any mapping $f:X\to S^1\times S^1$ induces a homomophism $f_*:G=\pi(X)\to\pi(S^1\times S^1)=\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$. If $G$ is finite, so is $f_*(G)$, and since the only finite subgroup of $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$ is $\{0\}$, we conclude $f_*(G)=\{0\}$ and by the lifting criterion there is $\widetilde f:X\to\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$. Clearly $\widetilde f$ is nullhomotopic, hence so is $f$.

Now, let $X=S^1\wedge S^1$ be the wedge of two circles, say $X=S^1\cup C$ where $C$ is another circle tangent to $S^1$ at a point $p$. You can extend the identity $S^1\to S^1$ to $g:X\to S^1$, just collapsing $C$ onto $p$. Finally compose $g$ with $S^1\equiv S^1\times\{p\}\subset S^1\times S^1$ to get $f:X\to S^1\times S^1$. We claim that $f$ is not nullhomotopic.

To see that, consider the fundamental group $\pi_1(X,(p,p))=\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$. This fundamental group is generated by the two fundamental loops $\sigma=S^1\times\{p\}$ and $\tau=\{p\}\times S^1$. 
Thus, the homomorphism $f_*$ induced in homotopy groups has the fundamental loop $\sigma$ in the image, hence that image cannot be trivial. So $f_*\ne0$ and consequently $f$ cannot be nullhomotopic.

Comment: Excuse me but i have a question About the second part , i don't understand the part where we map the circle to a loop and we get it in the image of f* can you explain it to me or write it down please ? I'm really thankful for your help  @JesusRS

Comment: I've rewritten a bit the post.

Comment: @Butterfly: It seems the answer is not accepted. But the important thing is whether there is something unclear and I can help you to solve the problem.

Comment: The thing is that I read both answers and I got lost because they are somehow contradicting each other , and regarding your answer , I don't get the S^1 x {p} what is p and why f* of the loop we didn't collapse is indeed this S^1 x{p} ? I'm really sorry for taking too long to understand it .. Thank you so much :) @JesusRS

Comment: I've tried to explain better my answer. Concerning the other answer, it explains the general facts concerning mappings $X\to S^1\times S^1$ where $X$ has finite fundamental group. The key property is that for such an $X$ all homomorphisms $\pi_1(X)\to G=\pi_1(S^1\times S^1)$ are trivial.

Comment: The second part of the question asks us that if we replaced the torus by the wedge sum ,does the claim holds..What you did at the end is taking f a function  to the torus again ,but that's not what is asked, so i'm all lost again  @JesusRS

Comment: You're right. By some reason I was replacing $X$ by the wedge. Then, it is more difficult. Although the wedge has a universal covering to which $f$ lifts (by the same argument with the fundamental group), that universal covering is the so-called Cayley graph. I'll think it over, and sorry for my misunderstanding

Answer (score 1):

basically it is true for any space $Y$ with fundamental group $G$ s.t there is no non-trivial homomorphism from $\pi_1(X) \to G$...and universal cover of $Y$ is contractible (basically $Y$ is a $K(G,1)$ space)...then by using map lifting criterion you can always get a lifting of your function $f$ on the universal cover where the image is contractible and composition with covering map will give you a null homotopy map for $f$ in $Y$.

Comment: Can I  suppose that X is R since the fundamental group of R is trivial hence finite, and then take f to be the functions that gives me a loop on one of the circles of the wedge sum, then this loop can't be shrunk to a cte loop ,therefore f is not nullhomotopic? is this true ?  @jesusRs

Comment: Since R is contractible so any continuous map is null homotopic.... Think!!